# iOS ZBarSDK how to detect when user dismiss QR Scanner (ViewController)

Tags: ios, objective-c, qr-code, zbar-sdk, zbar

In my code, I initialize `ZBarReaderViewController` for qr scanning.

I needed to detect when user quit the *QR Scanning* process without scanning any qr code.
Is there any ways that I can know when user quit that process (by clicking on cancel button in the view) and execute something right after `ZBarReaderViewController` is dismissed?

Thank you in advance. Any info is much appreciated!

**Below is my code to trigger qr scanning process by a click of a button.**

```
-(IBAction)nextBtn:(id)sender{

     NSLog(@"trigger QR CODE");

     if(!reader)
     {
         reader = [[ZBarReaderViewController alloc]init];
         reader.readerDelegate = self;
         reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

         ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
            // TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

            // EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
         [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                     config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                             to: 0];

         UIView * infoButton = [[[[[reader.view.subviews objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:3];

         [infoButton setHidden:YES];
     }

     // present and release the controller
     [self.view addSubview:spinner];
     [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
     [spinner startAnimating];

     [self presentViewController:reader animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

**This is how I capture the qr code when user scans one.**

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) imageReader
  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
 {
     // ADD: get the decode results
     id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
     [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
     ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
     for(symbol in results)
         // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
         break;


     NSString *receiptData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@-!-@%@", amountLabel.text, receiptLabel.text];

     isClosed = YES;
     NSLog(@"Completion");
     [reader dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
         [self BPUpdateTokenCollection:receiptData qrData:symbol.data];
         [reader.readerView stop];
          for(UIView *subViews in reader.view.subviews)
             [subViews removeFromSuperview];
         [reader.view removeFromSuperview];
         reader.view = nil;
         reader = nil;

      }];
  }
```

Comment: if you can deploy only on iOS7 is worth to mention that the last version of iOS includes barcode/qrcode detection API, easy to integrate and pretty reliable. If you can't there is also another library that is a user friendly wrapper around zxing https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC

Comment: Currently I am targeting iOS 7 and above. So basically this would be a great alternative way to implement QR scanner. Thanks for the info

Comment: A little tutorial to get how it can be implemented http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2013/10/11/ios7-day-by-day-day-16-decoding-qr-codes-with-avfoundation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
@protocol ZBarReaderDelegate <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>



ZBarReaderDelegate is nothing but UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel: (UIImagePickerController*) picker{

    //Cancelled 

    //Do your stuff here


}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Been searching for this for hours. Thanks!  Thumbs up!